# flatMap is giving compilation error with spring webflux

Tags: java-8, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm getting compile time error while using flatMap() in the below method:

The method flatMap(Function<? super List,? extends Mono<? extends R>>) in the type Mono<List> is not applicable for the
arguments (( customRefList) -> {})

```
public Mono<Boolean> isMandatory(String country, String compliance,String referenceType) {
        
        Flux<CustomReference> customRefFlux = getCustomsReferenceRule();
        return Mono.just(customRefFlux.collectList().flatMap(customRefList -> {
            customRefList.stream().anyMatch(customRef -> customRef.getType()
.equalsIgnoreCase(referenceType));
        }));
    }
```

Internally it is calling:

```
    public Flux<CustomReference> getCustomsReferenceRule() {
        CustomReference c1 = new CustomReference();
        c1.setCrKey("ECU");
        c1.setType("MRN");
        CustomReference c2 = new CustomReference();
        c2.setCrKey("FUE");
        c2.setType("FUE");
        Flux<CustomReference> custRefFlux = Flux.just(c1, c2);
        return custRefFlux;
    }
```

POJO class is

```
@Data
public class CustomReference {
    private String type;
    private String crKey;
}
```

Comment: isMandatory() always returns a Mono.just(Boolean.FALSE), so what is your actual intention?  also update with WHAT your compiler error is, dont write "it gives me a compiler error" are we supposed to guess or what?

Comment: As a general rule for thumb: *don’t use forEach* In your case, you need something like `return Mono.just(… flatMap(…) .anyMatch(…));`

Comment: @Holger:      Flux<CustomReference> customRefFlux = getCustomsReferenceRule(country,complianceType);
     return Mono.just(customRefFlux.collectList().flatMap(customRefList ->{
      customRefList.stream().anyMatch(customRef->customRef.getType().equalsIgnoreCase(referenceType));
      }));

Tried this still not working.

Comment: @Toerktumlare: Added the error. Please check

Comment: You are still putting the terminal operation inside the flatMap, instead of chaining it after it.

Comment: @Holger you mean to say the usage of collectList in Flux object? I'm doing that to get List<Objects> from Flux

Comment: You have `.flatMap(customRefList -> { customRefList.stream().anyMatch(…); }))` but it has to be `.flatMap(customRefList -> customRefList.stream()) .anyMatch(…)`. The `anyMatch` step must be *after* the `flatMap`, not inside it. Further, for a `Function`, the form of the lambda expression must be either, `arg -> expression` or `arg -> { return expression; }` but not `arg -> { statement; }`

Comment: @Holger I'm still not able to resolve it. Please post the complete solution if possible. I have provided the complete code in the question

Comment: `Flux.flatMap` requires you map into a `Publisher<R>`, but you return a `boolean`. You can avoid this problem all together by using `Flux.any`: `return customRefFlux.any(customRef -> customRef.getType().equalsIgnoreCase(referenceType))`

Answer (score 0):

Somehow managed like this, code is not concise but it does the job

```
        Flux<CustomReference> customRefFlux = getCustomsReferenceRule();
        return customRefFlux.collectList().flatMap(customRefList -> {

            List<CustomReference> l = customRefList.stream()
                    .filter(customRef -> customRef.getType().equalsIgnoreCase(referenceType))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            if (!l.isEmpty())
                return Mono.just(Boolean.TRUE);
            else
                return Mono.just(Boolean.FALSE);
        });
```