# Not able to return Mono of Boolean with Spring Webflux

Tags: java-8, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I want to return Mono of Boolean from the below method but getting compilation error with flatMap().

```
public Mono<Boolean> isMandatory(String country, String compliance,String referenceType) {
        
        Flux<CustomReference> customRefFlux = getCustomsReferenceRule();
        return Mono.just(customRefFlux.collectList().flatMap(customRefList -> {
            customRefList.stream().anyMatch(customRef -> customRef.getType()
.equalsIgnoreCase(referenceType));
        }));
    }
```

It is internally calling:

```
 public Flux<CustomReference> getCustomsReferenceRule() {
        CustomReference c1 = new CustomReference();
        c1.setCrKey("ECU");
        c1.setType("MRN");
        CustomReference c2 = new CustomReference();
        c2.setCrKey("FUE");
        c2.setType("FUE");
        Flux<CustomReference> custRefFlux = Flux.just(c1, c2);
        return custRefFlux;
    }
```

The POJO class

```
@Data
public class CustomReference {
    private String type;
    private String crKey;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [flatMap is giving compilation error with spring webflux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73531303/flatmap-is-giving-compilation-error-with-spring-webflux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely don't want to mix streams and collections unless needed. If I'm following this should be a simple:

```
public Mono<Boolean> isMandatory(String country, String compliance,String referenceType) {
    Flux<CustomReference> customRefFlux = getCustomsReferenceRule();
    return customRefFlux.any(customRef -> customRef.getType()
        .equalsIgnoreCase(referenceType));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    Flux<CustomReference> customRefFlux = getCustomsReferenceRule();
    return customRefFlux.collectList().flatMap(customRefList -> {

        List<CustomReference> l = customRefList.stream()
                .filter(customRef -> customRef.getType().equalsIgnoreCase(referenceType))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        if (!l.isEmpty())
            return Mono.just(Boolean.TRUE);
        else
            return Mono.just(Boolean.FALSE);
    });
```